# Using python to find the limit of a recusive function

Tags: recursion, sympy

Assume I had the following iterative fuction:

f(z) = z^2 + c
z initally equal to 0

and each answer of the function becomes z for the next iteration. i.e. if c is 1 then the fist iteration gives 1, the second gives 2 and so fourth.

Now assuming I already set a value for c, I would like to be able to use Python to find the limit as this function approaches an infinite number of iterations. How would I best be able to do that? Would Sympy be a good tool?

editied to clearify what I man by iterative function.

Comment: If there is a limit, then this limit has to be a fixed-point of *f*. I.e., if the limit is a number *z*, then this number has to satisfy *f(z) = z*. So you can solve the equation *z = z² + c* to find the set of candidates.

Comment: @Stef, does that argument hold true for an iterative function? I have edited my post in case I did not make myself clear the first time.

Comment: It's true for any continuous function *f* and sequence *u* defined by the recursive relation *u_(n+1) = f(u_n)*. Function *f* is not "iterative" by itself. It's just a continuous function. But if sequence *u* converges to a limit *z*, then this limit satisfies the equation *z = f(z)*.